# Including All Fields in MIN/Group By Query

Tags: sql, mysql, count, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have created my first MySQL query to get the minimum LTP by MarketName/SelectionName. It works ok but I'm struggling to work out how to get the rest of the fields from the original table (checktable).

I just want the records containing with the minimum LTP.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
SELECT MarketName, SelectionName, MIN(LTP) AS LTP 
FROM checktable 
WHERE MarketState = "Not In Play" AND SelectionID <> 0 AND CloseTime <> "" AND Result <> "" 
GROUP BY MarketName, SelectionName HAVING COUNT(*) > 900
```

Comment: You could either use this as a sub-query and join back to the `checktable` or use the aggregates function over a window.

Comment: On a side note: String literals should be enclosed by single quotes (e.g. `'Not In Play'`). Double quotes are for names in SQL (e.g. `MIN(ltp) AS "The minimum LTP"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MarketName, SelectionName ORDER BY LTP, checktable) AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MarketName, SelectionName) AS count 
  FROM checktable 
  WHERE MarketState = 'Not In Play' AND SelectionID <> 0 AND CloseTime <> '' AND Result <> '' 
)
SELECT * -- here you can select only the columns that you need
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND count > 900;
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas. Sometimes there are multiple MIN(LTP)s for each SelectionName so this returns multiple records. Is there a way to return just the first record?

Comment: @Andy Which one is the first? Is there a column that defines the order?

Comment: yes, I should have included it, apologies. It's called checktable.`Date/Time`

Comment: @Andy does this column have the same name as the table?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help in solving this. I have alos learned a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query result to select from the tabe again in order to get the complete rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM checktable 
WHERE (marketname, selectionname, ltp) IN
(
  SELECT marketname, selectionname, MIN(ltp) AS min_ltp
  FROM checktable 
  WHERE marketstate = 'Not In Play' 
    AND selectionid <> 0 
    AND closetime <> ''
    AND result <> '' 
  GROUP BY marketname, selectionname 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 900
)
ORDER BY marketname, selectionname;
```

Comment: ... but as I see in the other answer's comments now, you don't want those rows, but only some of them. This cannot be done with the subquery as shown in my answer. `ROW_NUMBER` as suggested by forpas is the best option to rank your rows.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I've learned some new things from this also.